# How can I generate a user table with email verification and automatic deletion of unverified accounts within 24 hours in SurrealDB?

Tags: surrealdb, surrealdb-rpc

I'm working on a project where I need to create a user table. One of the requirements is that users should verify their email addresses, and if an account remains unverified for 24 hours, it should be automatically deleted. I'm wondering if Surrealdb, a database management system, can directly work with Gmail for email verification. Alternatively, should I build an SMTP library for this purpose?

I have the following specific questions:

Can Surrealdb be integrated with Gmail to send verification emails?
If not, what is the recommended approach for implementing email verification and automatic account deletion in this scenario?
Are there any existing libraries or tools that can simplify this process?

WE did donsider time-based account deletion. Moreover, investigated SMTP functionality but there is webhook functionality for now which doesn't help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, SurrealDB does not have an SMTP feature. The best solution is to create the user as specified in the documentation, but set their status as unverified. You can then use a package like Nodemailer/SMTP transporter to send an email to the user, asking them to verify their account.